# In Visual Basic, how do I select a value from a text file and add it to a label on the GUI?

Tags: vb.net

Sorry if the question is confusing, I suck at Visual Basic.

The text file is a .txt file in the project folder. It has the following written in it.

```
 Game1
 3000
 Game2
 4000
```

In the GUI, I have a label. The label should say for example when it's visible, "Game1 is 3000" 
Now part of the code:

```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As      System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    intComboBox1Choice = Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
    Select Case intComboBox1Choice
        Case 0
            Game1()
        Case 1
            3000()
        Case 2
            Game2()
        Case 3
            4000()
    End Select

 Private Sub Game1()
    Me.lblLabel.Visible = True
    lblLabel.Text = "Game1 is"
 End Sub

 Private Sub Game2()
    Me.lblLabel.Visible = True
    lblLabel.Text = "Game1 is"
    End Sub
 End Sub
```

So as you can see the "3000" or "4000" values is in the text file and I want to display it in the label message so when I click Case 0 in the combobox, which will be Game1, the label would read "Game1 is 3000." how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

use io.file.streamreader to read the file then u can use the split function ti split the words and store in a string array.. then display those elrments from array to textbox

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can help.

```
Imports System.IO
...
Dim iValue() As Integer
...
Private Sub btnReadText_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReadText.Click
    Try
        Dim iCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim lines As String = ""
        Dim line_split As String()
        Dim str As String

        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("c:\so_vb_text.txt")
            lines = reader.ReadToEnd
            reader.Close()
        End Using

        line_split = lines.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        For Each str In line_split
            If str.Contains("Game") Then
                iCounter += 1
                cmbKey.Items.Add(str)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve iValue(iCounter)
                iValue(iCounter) = Int(str)
            End If
        Next

        cmbKey.SelectedIndex = 0

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbKey.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim iComboBoxChoice As Integer

    iComboBoxChoice = cmbKey.SelectedIndex

    lblLabel.Visible = True
    lblLabel.Text = "Game " & iComboBoxChoice + 1 & " is " & iValue(iComboBoxChoice + 1)

End Sub
...
```